# Passing Values from Core data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data

I currently have core data and I want to pass the coordinates of a selected pin that exists in the persistent store. So i filtered through the fetched Objects and matched with the view annotation coordinate. Location is an instance of my entity. My code below:

```
 var location: Location!
 var latitude: Double = 0.0
 var longitude: Double = 0.0

 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPhotos", sender: self)
            let savedPins = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!
        location = savedPins.filter({$0.latitude == view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude && $0.longitude == view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude}).first
            self.longitude = location.longitude
            self.latitude = location.latitude
    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? photoAlbumViewController {
            vc.dataController = dataController
            vc.longitude = longitude
            vc.latitude = latitude
}
```

When it segues, it does not send the coordinates on the first try, until I segue back the second time into the photoalbumviewcontroller, then I receive the first coordinate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are segueing before setting the variables. Change to this:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        let savedPins = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!
        location = savedPins.filter({$0.latitude == view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude && $0.longitude == view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude}).first
        self.longitude = location.longitude
        self.latitude = location.latitude

        //moved to after setting the variables
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPhotos", sender: self)

    }
```